# HTTP error handling to get data in low network areas

Tags: node.js, http, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hey guys I am using ionic 3 native HTTP to do HTTP requests to my backend server, I noticed in areas with low signal some HTTP requests go into the error handler of the HTTP request because it could not send the request due to low network signal.  I was wondering if anyone has advice or experience on if its a good idea to try and retry the HTTP request on the error handler so that it can try again to see if it can try and send the request again? If so how did you go about handling this properly?

Just trying to see how to make my ionic 3 app more stable in low signal areas.

Comment: I was thinking about if the request fails to retry in 3 seconds.  What do you guys think about this?

Comment: anyone have suggestions for this?